# Unexpected keyword filePath in rule definition

Tags: python, snakemake

my snakemake fails to lunch with error

```
$snakemake -s bsmooth_Snakefile.smk -np --forcerun
SyntaxError in file /scripts/bsmooth_snakemake/bsmooth_Snakefile.smk, line 9:
Unexpected keyword filePath in rule definition (bsmooth_Snakefile.smk, line 9)
```

here's how actual snakefile looks like

```
$ cat bsmooth_Snakefile.smk

configfile: "config/config.yaml"
configfile: "config/samples.yaml"

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("results/bsmooth_fit/{sample}/{sample}.fitted.rda", sample=config["samples"])
rule bsmooth_fit:
    input:
        filePath=lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.samples]
    output:
        bsfit="results/{rule}/{sample}/{sample}.fitted.rda"
    params:
        rscript=config["BSmooth_fit"]
    log:
        "logs/{rule}/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        "Rscript {params.rscript} --sample {wildcards.samples} --file {input.filePath} --outfile {output.bsfit} 2> {log}"
```

pls see attached `sample.yaml`

```
$cat sample.yaml

samples:
    Sample1Tumor: methylation_coverage/Sample1Tumor.bismark.cov.gz
    Sample1Norm: methylation_coverage/Sample1Norm.bismark.cov.gz
```

I'm also attaching the config.yaml that contains the script

```
$cat config.yaml
BSmooth_fit: scripts/bsmooth_snakemake.r
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think you need `filePath=`.

Comment: thanks for the tip but removing `filePath=` didn't work `SyntaxError Unexpected keyword lambda in rule definition (bsmooth_Snakefile.smk, line 9)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and make sure you are not mixing TAB and SPACES for indentation. You probably have a TAB character in front of `filePath`. Substitute all TABs with SPACEs and try again.